# Intercepting and changing canvas font

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to automatically intercept and change the font and return the canvas data url via canvas.dataToUrl()

So whenever toDataURL is called it changes the font size by 0.01 and returns back the toDataURL

```
<script>

Object.defineProperty(HTMLCanvasElement, 'toDataURL', {
    //Change Font and return the toDataURL
    //this.font = this.font + 0.01
    //return toDataURL
  });

const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 280;
canvas.height = 60;
canvas.style.display = "none"
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.fillStyle = "rgb(102, 204, 0)";
context.fillRect(100, 5, 80, 50);
context.fillStyle = "#f60";
context.font = "16pt Arial";
context.fillText("<@nv45. F1n63r,Pr1n71n6!", 10, 40);
context.strokeStyle = "rgb(120, 186, 176)";
context.arc(80, 10, 20, 0, Math.PI, !1);
context.stroke();
const canvasValue = canvas.toDataURL();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const orgToDataURL = canvas.toDataURL.bind(canvas); //Original function
    document.body.append(canvas);
    canvas.width = 280;
    canvas.height = 60;
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    function draw(font) {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.fillStyle = "rgb(102, 204, 0)";
        context.fillRect(100, 5, 80, 50);
        context.fillStyle = "#f60";
        context.font = font;
        context.fillText("<@nv45. F1n63r,Pr1n71n6!", 10, 40);
        context.strokeStyle = "rgb(120, 186, 176)";
        context.arc(80, 10, 20, 0, Math.PI, !1);
        context.stroke();
    }
    draw("16px Arial");

    canvas.toDataURL = function() { //Overwrite function
        draw((parseFloat(context.font) + 0.1) + "px Arial");
        return orgToDataURL();
    };

    setInterval(function() {
        console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
    }, 500);
</script>
```